# DB2:LUW:Windows(OS) Unable to Call Java UDF

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am following the steps outlined in the URL
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/viewdocument/generating-universally-unique-ident?CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a&tab=librarydocuments to call Java UDF from DB2 database.

```
import java.util.UUID;       // for UUID class
 
public class UUIDUDF
{
  public static String randomUUID()
  {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

I am able to generate JAR and I called

`call sqlj.install_jar('file:///C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/UDF/UUIDUDF.jar', 'UUIDUDFJAR')`

and I am able to find Jar being deployed at

"C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\function\jar\DB2ADMIN"

I restarted database manager using db2stop and db2start command..when i call the function I am getting error

> "Java‬‎ ‪stored‬‎ ‪procedure‬‎ ‪or‬‎ ‪user‬‎-‪defined‬‎ ‪function‬‎
> ‪‬‎"‪DB2ADMIN.RANDOMUUID"‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪specific‬‎ ‪name‬‎
> ‪‬‎"‪SQL200817125101637"‬‎ ‪could‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪load‬‎ ‪Java‬‎ ‪class‬‎
> ‪‬‎"‪C:\PROGRAMDATA\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1"‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪reason‬‎ ‪code‬‎
> ‪‬‎"‪"‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪4304‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪42724‬‎,‪‬‎
> ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪19‬‎.‪56"...

I created the function using below code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RANDOMUUID()
  RETURNS VARCHAR(36)
  LANGUAGE JAVA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
  NOT DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION NO SQL
  EXTERNAL NAME 'UUIDUDFJAR:UUIDUDF.randomUUID' ;
```

But when I generate DDL for my function in Db2 instance I am missing Jar reference in External name  (EXTERNAL NAME 'UUIDUDF.randomUUID')

```
CREATE FUNCTION "DB2ADMIN"."RANDOMUUID" ()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(36 OCTETS)
    SPECIFIC "DB2ADMIN"."SQL200817125101637"
    NO SQL
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    DISALLOW PARALLEL
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    EXTERNAL NAME 'UUIDUDF.randomUUID'
    FENCED THREADSAFE
    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    NOT SECURED;
```

Could you please help me understand what i am missing here?

Thank you,
Pavan.

Comment: The routine from the article works as described on my 11.1.4.4 on Windows. 
What's the result of the following query? `SELECT JARSCHEMA, JAR_ID, CLASS, IMPLEMENTATION
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINESCHEMA='DB2ADMIN' AND ROUTINENAME='RANDOMUUID'`. What's your db2 version?

Comment: What's the output of `jar tf C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\function\jar\DB2ADMIN\UUIDUDF.jar`?

Comment: Than you for your responses..DB2ADMIN(JARSCHEMA)  UUIDUDFJAR(JAR ID) UUIDUDF(Class) randomUUID()Ljava/lang/String;� (IMPLEMENTATION )..I also added sample java code to original post as well. MY DB2 version is DB2 LUW 11.5

Comment: META-INF,  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ,UUIDUDF.class

Comment: I dont see  javac the java compiler is on my path variable, but still I am able to execute commands javac UUIDUDF.java and create .class file, not sure if that is the issue

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 10 x64 with Db2 V11.5.4.0

Comment: You wrote that your Db2-LUW version is 11.5, but your jdbc driver version looks like some special build of V10.5.  Double check your environment.